# Linking between two plotly graphs in R or Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, interactive

I am trying to link two plots using plotly (either in R or Shiny). Below is an example. The dataset contains ten observations that each have five variables (A, B, C, D, E). I make a scatterplot that contains all ten observations (ten dots), where only the first two variables (A and B) are used for x and y values:

```
library(plotly)
library(data.table)

dat <- data.frame(ID = paste0("ID",1:10), A = runif(10), B = runif(10), C = runif(10), D = runif(10), E = runif(10))
dat$ID <- as.character(dat$ID)

plot_ly(data = dat, x = ~A, y = ~B)
```

[image: scatterplot]

After that, I use the same dataset to create a line plot of the ten observations (ten lines). Only now, each observation (line) contains all five variables (A, B, C, D, E).

```
datt <- data.frame(t(dat))

names(datt) <- as.matrix(datt[1, ])
datt <- datt[-1, ]
datt[] <- lapply(datt, function(x) type.convert(as.character(x)))
setDT(datt, keep.rownames = TRUE)[]
colnames(datt)[1] <- "x"

dat_long <- melt(datt, id.vars ="x" )

p <- plot_ly(dat_long, x= ~x, y= ~value, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines+markers', color = ~variable)  %>% layout(dragmode="box", showlegend = FALSE)
```

[image: lineplot]

I notice that, for both the scatterplot and lineplot, I can use the box select tool to highlight a point of interest. I am trying to use this to create a link between the two plots. So if a user clicked a certain point (or points) in the scatterplot, then they would see the corresponding line (or lines) in the lineplot.

I am familiar with Shiny, and wonder if this could be used to allow for the linkage between plotly graphs. For instance, if a user highlighted a certain point, then I could somehow save that variable as a "user input", and then have the line plot render that new input to create its new output (i.e. showing the corresponding line.

Is it possible to link these plots, either in R or Shiny? And/or, Is it possible to save information about how the user interacts with which points or lines?

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: With Shiny, you can use `event_data()`like in [this example](https://plot.ly/r/shiny-coupled-events/)